# How can I see my accumulated query costs for BigQuery while in the free trial?

Tags: google-bigquery

Google Cloud billing is not updating with the free trial (on monthly payments) and I can not change it to a faster update cycle. As per https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/billing-during-free-trial the bill should come every month.

It is therefore not easy to see how much of the 300$ is left.

Is there any way to at least see how many TBs my queries used? This should be by far the biggest item on the bill.

I am concerned that I might get 'stuck' between some important queries that I otherwise could have managed better to have at least partial results available after the trial ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery analysis & storage costs should be listed under your GCP billing transactions:

[https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/<**INSERT_YOUR_BILLING_ID_HERE**>/history?e=13803970,13803205](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/%3C**INSERT_YOUR_BILLING_ID_HERE**%3E/history?e=13803970,13803205)

Another way to see how much you have queried is by enabling audit logging as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs).

Comment: the billing transactions does not work (because no bills have been sent yet, monthly?)

but the audit logging works fine, although a little more work than I hoped for