# BigQuery bill breakdown?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, firebase-analytics

I have my bill estimate within my cloud console. Is there a way that I can get a breakdown of what it's actually charging me for before actually getting the bill?

Comment: you already see there lines such as storage, queries, streaming inserts.

Comment: Did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462269/how-can-i-see-my-accumulated-query-costs-for-bigquery-while-in-the-free-trial/41463248#41463248